# Changing display of time in a .bat script

Tags: batch-file, time

I have the following:

```
echo %date:~-10,10% %time:~0,8%
```

I use this to save date and time in a text file. The problem is that when the time is, let's say 09:15, it shows as

```
08/04/2014  9:15:00
```

So there is a double space between 4 and 9. Is there any way to modify this script so that when the time is single digit it will instead insert a 0?

So that the end result will look like the following:

```
08/04/2014 09:15:00
```

And when the time is for instance 10:00 it displays like:

```
08/04/2014 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set "mytime=%time: =0%"
echo %date:~-10,10% %mytime:~0,8%
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am just wondering, if the time is for instance 10:00, will it then add a "0" in front of the 1, hence displaying "010:00" or does the ":~0,8%" trim away the extra 0 if time is double digit?

Comment: I believe the display replaces the leading 0 with a space. What this command does is replace all spaces in the "variable" `%time%` with zeroes. Since `10:00` does not contain the leading space, it should have no effect on `10:00`

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to test this tomorrow and I'll get back to you. :-)